# add a new element in a array of objects typescript angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

i have the array:

```
{"succees":false,"message":"","success":true,"customers":
    [{"id_customers":2,
        "code_customers":"123444444",
        "trade_name":"world",
        }
    ]},
    [{"id_customers":1,
        "code_customers":"4444",
        "trade_name":"hello",
        }
    ]}
}
```

How can i include a new element in all of the objects to the array??

I want to do this:

```
{"succees":false,"message":"","success":true,"customers":
    [{"id_customers":2,
        "code_customers":"123444444",
        "trade_name":"world",
        "collapse":true,   // The new element i want to include
        }
    ]},
    [{"id_customers":1,
        "code_customers":"4444",
        "trade_name":"hello",
        "collapse":true,   // The new element i want to include
        }
    ]}
}
```

I am using angular to do this in my component, but i dont know how can i do that..

Any help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use `Array.map`:

```js
const res = {...your object};
res.customers.map((c: any) => c.collapse = true);
```

Comment: My array is called customer, so the correct way to do that is const res = {this.customer};
res.customers.map((c: any) => c.collapse = true); is that right??

Comment: Try it. Just use `map` on the customer array. Ideally, edit  the question so that the code is formatted and put there some more context. It is not clear, what `this.customer` is.